# Create an access token using VSTS service endpoint by passing Username and Password as input

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to generate access token via VSTS service endpoint by passing username and password as parameters.

The token is being generated via Azure AD.

I have written an c# method to create the token and the token is being generated successfully,whereas i am not sure how to call the c# method(dll) from the vsts extension file(vss-extension.json) so the token gets generated when i enter my username and password in the custom service endpoint connection.

Here is the vss-extension.json and the VSTS custom endpoint picture for creating custom service endpoint.
I dont know where exactly and what exactly to add here which will call my C#(.dll) file .
Is there any other approach for creating a token if possible kindly suggest.

```
"authenticationSchemes": [
      {
        "type": "ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-auth-scheme-token",

       "headers": [{
            "name": "Authorization",
            "value": "{{ endpoint.apitoken }}"
        }],
        "inputDescriptors": [{
            "id": "apitoken",
    "name": "API Key",
    "description": "API key for connection",
    "inputMode": "textbox",
    "isConfidential": false,
    "validation": {
      "isRequired": true,
      "dataType": "string"
            }
        }]
      },
      {
        "type": "ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-auth-scheme-basic",
        "inputDescriptors": [
          {
            "id": "username",
            "name": "Username",
            "description": "Username",
            "inputMode": "textbox",
            "validation": {
              "isRequired": false,
              "dataType": "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "password",
            "name": "Password",
            "description": "Password",
            "inputMode": "passwordbox",
            "isConfidential": true,
            "validation": {
              "isRequired": false,
              "dataType": "string"
            }
          }
        ]
      }


    ],
```

[image]